# Php How To Echo Null from MySql

Tags: mysql

I have the following script that I use for part of my count in payment_status from Mysql. I have seen some examples of this online, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work WITH a Null instance. Any insight would be appreciated.

Note: The way I have it now doesn't work when Null is in the database. I'm guessing because that isn't an inserted word?

Objective: To add $row['payment_status'] == "Null" to this with the rest of the script.

```
if($row['payment_status'] == "Completed" || $row['payment_status'] == "Free" || $row['payment_status'] == "Cancelled" || $row['payment_status'] == "Null")
```

Comment: `NULL` means? default value in `payment_status` column? if Yes then check without double quote `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if payment_status column has default value NULL, Then try below change

```
if($row['payment_status'] == "Completed" || $row['payment_status'] == "Free" || $row['payment_status'] == "Cancelled" || $row['payment_status'] == null)
```

Comment: Ahhhh yes that did the trick. Thank you. I see why now.